# Selenium SessionNotCreated Exception in eclipse

Tags: selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

1. I have tried with updated version of chrome brower
2. tried with firefox and edge browser.
3. Tried updating selenium version still I am unable to resolve this issue.

please help -

org.openqa.selenium.SessionNotCreatedException: Could not start a new session. Possible causes are invalid address of the remote server or browser start-up failure.
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:585)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.startSession(RemoteWebDriver.java:248)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.(RemoteWebDriver.java:164)
at org.openqa.selenium.chromium.ChromiumDriver.(ChromiumDriver.java:108)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:106)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:93)
at org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver.(ChromeDriver.java:48)
at Basics.FirstTestSelenium.testFindElements(FirstTestSelenium.java:61)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:133)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeMethod(TestInvoker.java:598)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethod(TestInvoker.java:173)
at org.testng.internal.MethodRunner.runInSequence(MethodRunner.java:46)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker$MethodInvocationAgent.invoke(TestInvoker.java:824)
at org.testng.internal.TestInvoker.invokeTestMethods(TestInvoker.java:146)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:146)
at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:128)
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach(ArrayList.java:1511)
at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:794)
at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:596)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:377)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:371)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:332)
at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:276)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:96)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1212)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1134)
at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1063)
at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1031)
at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:115)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:251)
at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:77)
Caused by: org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Driver server process died prematurely.
Build info: version: '4.1.3', revision: '7b1ebf28ef'
System info: host: 'HP-5CG1376V12', ip: '192.168.0.100', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '17.0.3'
Driver info: driver.version: ChromeDriver
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverService.start(DriverService.java:226)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:98)
at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:567)
... 35 more

Comment: Please add the code which you are using

Answer (score 0):

This might happens when there are no available ports for ChromeDriver within your system
Try the following steps

1. Do a System Reboot to free up ports
2. use Latest Chrome Browser and Driver version
3. Check your firewall settings and if its blocking chrome driver from accessing network

Try starting Chromedriver on a specific free port by specifying it

```
WebDriver driver= new ChromeDriver(new ChromeDriverService.Builder().usingPort(2291).build());
driver.get("https://www.google.com/");
```